# How to join two SELECT statements?

Tags: mysql, select

```
SELECT fullname,
SUM(IF(mark='c',1,0)) AS compensations,
ROUND(AVG(mark)) AS avg_mark
FROM evaluation
WHERE subject='$subject' AND fullname IN
(SELECT fullname
FROM campus
WHERE user_levels=1)
GROUP BY fullname ASC


SELECT fullname,
SUM(IF(attend='a',1,0)) AS absences
FROM attendance 
WHERE subject='subject I' AND fullname IN
(SELECT fullname FROM campus WHERE user_levels=1) 
GROUP BY fullname ASC
```

I need to display for each student that matches the statements: fullname, avg_mark, compensations and average.

The two codes work excellent on their own, but I cannot seem to put them together. Please, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: if you have a fullname column in tables evaluation and attendance and campus then your schema is de-normalized

Comment: @DrewPierce Why? Even if there is a separate `Student` table somewhere, `fullname` might be used as its primary key.

Comment: sure thing. Natural keys that change. run with it

Answer (score 0):

Those tables look very strange indeed. Why would you store fullname in 3 different tables? Doesn't look right.

Also:

- use INNER JOIN in preference to IN ( ... )
- recommend using case expressions over an IF() function

However, I think the following might work:

```
SELECT
      c.fullname
    , SUM(CASE
            WHEN e.mark = 'c' THEN 1
            ELSE 0
      END) AS compensations
    , ROUND(AVG(e.mark)) AS avg_mark
    , SUM(CASE
            WHEN a.attend = 'a' THEN 1
            ELSE 0
      END) AS absences
FROM campus c
LEFT JOIN evaluation e
      ON c.fullname = e.fullname
      AND e.subject = '$subject'
LEFT JOIN attendance a
      ON c.fullname = a.fullname
      AND a.subject = 'subject I'
WHERE c.user_levels = 1
GROUP BY c.fullname
;
```